# The plane arrives/will arrive at 3:30

Tags: future-tense

> The plane arrives/will arrive at 3:30.

My Approach:

I think the the sentence express a prediction by the person or guess and hence I used will.Though it is not explicitly mentioned to be prediction but can be used in this sense.Hence,I used will arrive

Am I right in my approach?Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are ***right!***

We use *the present tense* for the things that are going to happen for *sure*.

> The plane arrives at 3;30 am

Likewise,

> The show ***starts*** at 1800 hr 
>  The movie **begins** in 10 minutes

And so on...

`'Will'` is also fine. But, if you want to express a doubt, you may add 'probably'

> The plane will *probably* arrive at 3;30 am

Comment: Agree with maulik v